# How to incrementally query a child process at certain sync-points asynchronously in Node (without complicating things)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, child-process

I am trying to interface an incremental SMT solver from Node.js. It works something like this: I send commands on standard in asynchronously and the solver does its thing. At certain points, I want to query the solver for the result by sending the `check-sat` command and wait for the result to arrive on standard out. At other points, I want to start over by sending `reset`. Right now, I just want to get the result, but in the future, I would also need to have a timeout for the waiting.

There is some previous art in [the Aratha symbolic execution framework](https://github.com/ArathaJS/aratha/blob/master/lib/smt.js#L9), which uses a queue of callbacks with manual promises to handle these events. However, that solution seems like incidental complexity to me; I would prefer something more straightforward.

The solution I currently have looks like this:

```js
const {
    spawn
} = require("child_process");


// Think of this as a state in an automata waiting for the answer
async function askIfSat(context) {
    context.writeToOstrich("(check-sat)");

    for await (const chunk of context.ostrich.stdout) {
        // WARNING: I am not sure if a "chunk" is always a...line, or how this
        // works. May be half a command and we may need to keep a buffer of some
        // length and check it.
        let output = chunk.toString('utf8').trim();
        console.log(`Watcher: output: ${output}`);
        if (output === "sat") {
            return true;
        }

        if (output === "unsat") {
            return false;
        }

    }

    // Watch for process termination while we wait
    const exitCode = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        context.ostrich.on('close', resolve);
    });

    throw new Error(`subprocess error exit ${exitCode}`);
}


class Context {
    constructor() {
        this.ostrich = spawn("/Users/albin/ostrich/ostrich",
            ["+stdin", "+incremental", "-logo"], {
                stdio: [
                    "pipe",
                    "pipe",
                    "pipe",
                ]
            });

        this.ostrich.on("exit", console.error);
        this.ostrich.on("error", console.error);

        console.log("Spawning ostrich...");
    }

    writeToOstrich(cmd) {
        console.log(`Context: Writing >>${cmd}`);
        this.ostrich.stdin.write(cmd + "\n");
    }
}

async function testAssertion(assertion, ctx) {
    ctx.writeToOstrich("(reset)");
    ctx.writeToOstrich(assertion);
    let satStatus = await askIfSat(ctx);
    console.log(`${assertion} is sat? ${satStatus}`);
}

async function main() {
    let ctx = new Context();

    await testAssertion("(assert (= 18 18))", ctx);
    await testAssertion("(assert (= 18 1))", ctx);

    ctx.writeToOstrich("(exit)");
}

main()
```

The output I get is this:

```
npm test

> ostrich@1.0.0 test /Users/albin/ostrich-js
> babel-node index.js

Spawning ostrich...
Context: Writing >>(reset)
Context: Writing >>(assert (= 18 18))
Context: Writing >>(check-sat)
Watcher: output: sat
(assert (= 18 18)) is sat? true
Context: Writing >>(reset)
Context: Writing >>(assert (= 18 1))
Context: Writing >>(check-sat)
[freezes waiting for input]
```

Clearly, something goes wrong after the first call, but I cannot figure out what or why.

What would be the idiomatic way of doing this sort of thing?

Comment: I don't think the `Watch for process termination while we wait` part works. If the process really terminates between the two `testAssertion` calls, then surely you'd have to spawn it again?

Comment: You might have a point! In fact the process _shouldn’t_ terminate and I was just watching for it to do so because a) I saw it on another reply on stack overflow and b) I thought it might be a good idea to handle that case.

Comment: I'm pretty certain the asynchronous iterator will end when the process terminates or something like that.

Comment: And it won't end when I execute the `return` statement?

Comment: Oh, wait, I didn't see that you were only waiting for the `close` event to happen when the iterator has ended (unexpectedly) and you want to throw an exception. This should work. Unless the stream was closed before that, then you won't get another `close` event.

Comment: For whatever reason, it doesn't. I managed to get something like what I wanted working by building off of the solution I linked in my question, but I'd like to know why this one doesn't work.